# Share internet speed, locally?

Tags: networking

In some countries, like us, people do care about internet speed. So i was thinking about torrent like, internet speed sharing system. Our ISP's are interconnected and we get good local speed , and very poor internet speed. Local p2p between two pc has low ping.

So my crazy idea is, lets imagine two user, A and B. Both are interconnected via different ISP. So they use an "imaginary" software that sits in the machine. This software works in a proxy, with a single port. A user has 2mp/s connection and B user has 1mb/s connection. So when A user is idle , or barely using, it , B forward some connection request to A. A get the request, establish internet connection with server, get the packets and forward it at local speed to B. B gets the packets and send them to output buffer. Thus whatever B is downloading , speed should increase.

Can you guys say it is even possible, or feasible , or worth trying ? Cause we are in vacation and we have this crazy idea to implement !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you have two physical locations, with two different ISPs, referred to as A and B above.

Speeds for A are 2Mb/s while speeds for B are 1Mb/s.  Speeds from B to the internet are slow, let's say 50b/s, and the Sppeds from A to the internet are good, let's say it gets the full 2Mb/s.

For some strange reason though, you can get really good speeds between B and A, close to the 1 Mb/s that it's limited to.

If this is the scenario you're trying to address, you could try tunneling your traffic from B through A to the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ernie. We are trying to tunnel traffic with software. We have plan to put user ratio and DHT table to track users and all of other torrent things to distribute the bandwidth more wisely.

Comment: I made the above reply literally understanding the word "tunneling traffic". If there is certain terminology , or something already implemented somewhere , or it's a totally different thing, please explain a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a tunnel splitter: http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/tunnel-splitter-accelerating-a-single-tcp-connection-over-multiple-isps/

Comment: I don't think the user has multiple ISPs at the same location . . . I think they're asking about sharing a connection from two remote locations.

Comment: Very much close to what we think, but rather than the software sitting in the server splitting connections, it'll be a p2p software processing and forwarding  each others request on available internet bandwidth basis. Users will communicate between themselves in local speed so bottleneck does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

[As Sun said](https://superuser.com/a/621500/53590), you could use a tunnel splitter, or your could use a dual-WAN router that supports load balancing.

At work we use RV042 routers by Linksys. They support load balancing that essentially distributes client traffic across two ISPs, which would suit what you're trying to accomplish. There is also a Gigabit model.

http://www.neweggbusiness.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9B-33-124-160

Comment: very good hardware related solution, but we are trying to implement this through software. Anyway, tunnel splitter is very intriguing :)